# Should +1 and "I'll vote for you" style comments be allowed in nomination comments?

Tags: discussion, voting, election, nominations

Voting for nominations is not allowed. This makes sense - voting shouldn't start until everyone is ready. This allows late entries to get just as many votes as early ones when the election starts.

Comments seem to break this rule. Nearly every candidate has a, "+1 I'll vote for you" style message that gets  voted on in lieu of the actual nomination post. These posts add very little other than serving as a way to vote early.

Should this be allowed, or is it working against the system?

Comment: Why not? They don't really mean anything. You should take all public pronouncements of voting intentions with a dirty great pinch of salt.

Comment: @ChrisF If they don't mean anything then why are they there?

Comment: Because some people feel the need to post something? I don't know you'd have to ask the people posting those comments.

Comment: -1[...](http://herpderpironiccommentisironic.com)

Comment: I agree those comments are technically noise, but elections are a community event. There is bound to be all sorts of chatting, support, criticism and discussion in comments. That's part of the fun really!

Comment: It's the SO stand-in for a pre-election poll. As crazy as it sounds, it encourages discussion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see (a tiny bit) where you are coming from, but you should look at the previous [election](https://stackoverflow.com/election/1). To me, the comments are all about support. I support these guys (and hopefully gals) who step up to try for a spot at the nomination. Sometimes people need that. No political agenda intended just a pat on the back.

*Besides, comments are removed in the primary.*

Comment: For those who are nominated but are not elected, at least they got a bit of encouragement from someone who has noticed them enough to leave an appreciative comment :)