# Moderator nominations are showing up in the mod queue

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, moderator-tools, election

The Community user flagged one of the [moderator nominations](https://stackoverflow.com/election) for having more than 20 comments in the past 3 days.

[image: Flagged Nomination]

I know the flag is technically true and we can just dismiss it, but all the nominations are bound to get more than 20 comments.  Can we have Community stop doing that?

Comment: It makes sense for questions and answers but not nominations. +1

Comment: Also note the alluring "delete post" button, an option which does not appear on the nominations page.  We could wreak some havoc with that.  It's a good thing you trust us!  :)

Comment: Do they really need those comments? Most are "you have my vote, yay memez0r" crap :P

Comment: @MatthewRead http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111300/should-1-and-ill-vote-for-you-style-comments-be-allowed-in-nomination-commen

Comment: I like how it says "**answered** 4 hours ago" in the mod queue, as well as how egregiously off-topic the first paragraph of my post is, making that "delete post" button so much more tempting :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Trivial fix, will be there in the next deploy

```
 if (!(post.IsQuestion || post.IsAnswer)) return;
```

Comment: any other things this could impact? wikis?

Comment: well we do not allow flagging on wikis yet, nor do we allow commenting